# Cant make SFML work

Tags: c++, sfml

I am having an error when I try to create the first window in SFML.

the error says: The code execution cannot proceed because sfml-system-d-2.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.

All my includes work and i have no syntax error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713275/sfml-window-2-dll-is-missing-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder, the same one with your stdafx.h file, you need to place the sfml .dll files. When you are setting up your sfml project under project properties -> Debug -> Linker -> Input (Additional Dependencies) you should have sfml-graphics-d.lib...etc. Then you have to make sure that you copy these .dll files into your main project folder.[image]